# .NET: How do I find the Desktop path when Folder Redirection is on?

Tags: .net

I have been using

> Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)

to get the path to the user's desktop for ages now, but since we changed our setup here at work so we use Folder Redirection to map our users' **Desktop** and **My Documents** folders to the server, it no-longer works.  It still points to the **Desktop** folder in **C:\Documents and Settings**, which is not where my desktop lives.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Burns

Answer (score 9):

You need to use the DesktopDirectory special folder instead:

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)`

should give you the redirected directory.